# FreeBSD: FIFO в kernel-space

Tags: freebsd, kernel

Возможно ли создание FIFO из kernel-space'а? На lists.freebsd.ord наткнулся на следующий [тред](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-stable/2005-June/016065.html):

> A: To cut a long story short, how can I open a FIFO in kernel space and
> write to it, so I can open and read from it in userspace ?
>
> B: Why don't you create a device node? If you read and write to it, it acts like a FIFO.

Однако, о FIFO так ничего и не было сказано.

Comment: Вообще, FIFO - аббревиатура, означающая "первый вошел - первый вышел". Что вы здесь подразумеваете под FIFO? Механизм, позволяющий юзермоду общаться с ядром в FIFO порядке? Так там ответили что этот механизм - character devices.

Comment: @arrowd, Что вы здесь подразумеваете под FIFO?
Я подразумеваю канал FIFO, который создается командой mkfifo

Comment: @arrowd, Так там ответили что этот механизм - character devices.
Все верно. А я спрашиваю именно про FIFO каналы.

Comment: @arrowd, Вообще, FIFO - аббревиатура, означающая "первый вошел - первый вышел" -> 
вообще, увидев бы таг freebsd я бы в первую очередь подумал о FIFO как о спец. типе файлов, а не о способе манипулирования данными.